# Redirect http to https, www to non-www and remove last slash in one redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, seo

is it possible to redirect http to https, www to non-www and remove last slash in one htaccess redirect and it can be seo friendly?

I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

and I don't know how to add to this redirect removing last slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code for a single redirect to handle all 3 cases:

```
RewriteEngine On

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,E=DELSLASH:1]

# perform redirect for 1. www removal, 2. trailing / removal and 3. http->https
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_DELSLASH} =1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```